# Does assist mode permanently mark your file?

Tags: celeste

According to the Celeste Wiki, enabling [Assist Mode](https://celeste.ink/wiki/Assist_Mode) marks your save file with a blue badge.

If I enable Assist Mode on a level then go back and beat the level afterwards without using assists, will it remove the assist badge? Or does enabling assist mode permanently mark your save with an assist badge?

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't permanently mark your file anymore. In the first version it did, but they changed it to not be a jerk to people who need accessibility mode.

Comment: How does it work now? The wiki said the mark was changed, but it still sounded like the file gets marked